Is the following scenario really atomic?
Working through a multiprocessor textbook, and I have a question related to if a specific execution sequence is atomic -> it "intuitively" feels not atomic, but I can't seem to prove this fact given the conditions of atomicity.
For notation, we say that Read_i is the ith read of a shared location, and Write_i is the ith write. We say that E_1->E_2 if the event E_1 finishes before E_2 begins.
Firstly, the book offers the following definition for an atomic register (I would like to construct this proof with this definition, rather than any other definition)
Read_i -> Write_i is impossible
Write_i -> Write_j -> Read_i is impossible
Read_i -> Read_j => i <= j

Now consider the following scenario:
ThreadA---Write(W_1)------Read(W_1)---Read(W_2)
ThreadB----Write(W_2)-------------------------

Intuitively, this does not "feel" atomic: there are no writes that happened between ThreadA's two reads, and yet the read value still changed! But we verify each of the properties:

Read_i -> Write_i does not happen: we only read values that were written in the past
Write_i -> Write_j -> Read_i also does not happen: neither write precedes the other and so we have no writes such that W1 -> W2
Again, this is also met! We have that Read(W_1) -> Read(W_2), and indeed 1 <= 2.

So it seems that this scenario is atomic, and yet it shouldn't be. Is there an error in my logic somewhere? Or are atomics just not as reliable as one would hope...



It may be worth revisiting Lamport's definition of an atomic register in IPC I & II.


Threads won't necessarily care for your typesetting: just because your Write(W_2) occurs to the left of Read(W_1) need not mean that the former finishes before the latter begins. These diagrams typically serve as a means to describe Lamport causality but no more.


